# Is it better to write to file in small chunks or everything at once?

Tags: perl, memory, file-io

I have to write multiple lines on a file with Perl, which are the pros or the cons of writing in small chunks line by line versus saving everything up and accessing the filehandle only once to write everything?

Comment: Are you really asking if saving everything in memory will use more memory than not saving everything in memory?

Comment: If you can write data close to the point of it's creation and free the memory used by that data, you will use less memory, than saving all that data up somewhere and write it in one go. It would be helpfull if you could give us some more specifics as to what you want to achieve to help us give a better answer.

Comment: sorry the question was not well posed. it was a general question on whether it's better to write things as soon as possible, even if it means accessing the file many times, or limit the number of accesses to the file by accumulating data and writing it all at once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perl performs buffering of file writing under the hood--it saves up the data until there is a significant chunk, then writes it all at once.

Thus, even if you write to a *file handle* many times, the number of actual writes to a file is limited.  There will be no meaningful performance penalty for writing lots of times--unless you do something to explicitly circumvent the buffering (such as setting `$|=1` or closing and reopening the file each time you write).

You should just write line by line, if that is most convenient.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally more convenient to write the data as soon as you know what the data to write will be, so do that.  There is no disadvantage to using the filehandle repeatedly.

And, yes, that will save some memory if the total amount of data written is larger than the size of the output buffer, but, really, unless you're writing multiple dozens of megabytes, the difference in memory consumption *doesn't matter*, so write it in the way that will be clearest and most easily maintained.

Comment: Thanks, i thought that maybe the act of accessing a filehandle multiple times could be cumbersome; not really an IT expert here.